# MVC 2 - Images and CSS do not display on website

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-2, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have one MVC2 site that does not display the images and css or allow a user to login. All the other MVC 2 sites are working fine and have the exact same settings for the application pool. I'm using IIS8.5 and windows server 2012 R2.

**Application Pool Settings**

- Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated
- Identity: Application Pool Identity

The website works correctly on my own PC.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Check the folder permissions for the folders in question, make sure the app pool identity has the appropriate permissions to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work. It turned out to be duplicate MIME Types.